# Ntp synchronization video WP7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, synchronization, ntp

I guys:)

I am doing an windows phone application that presents videos, but presents when syncronized with an ntp server. I already have a variable with the time but i don´t know now what to do. I try search in google but i dont find anything.. I want to make an application to present the same video at the same time in different phones..

Any help? Examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get multiple devices doing something in sync is to define a time at which they should all start (do this on a central server) and then have each device request the amount of time to wait until the start. Each device should then start playback when that period has elapsed.

If you need to have different devices join in at specific ppoints when some are already playing the video your central point will need to send the point to start playing as well as the amount of time to wait until playback shoudl begin.

Due to the latency of the network communication you won't be able to get perfect sync though.

Comment: @jpmd I don't have an example as it's not a common thing to do. I've done time syncing via sockets but am not currently able to share that code.

Comment: thanks for the help.. I try to solve it:) i need to do this and i know some things but i also have doubts in some questions. But you explain me waht to do so i search and i try:)